# A compact set contains sup and inf

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $A$ be nonempty, compact. Then, $\sup A$ and $\inf A$ exist are elements of $A$.

Pf. By Heine-Borel, $A$ is closed and bounded. By the completeness axiom, a bounded set of the reals has a sup and inf, so we have existence.

I'm not sure how to show they're actually elements in $A$. I know I can choose $x_n\in A$ with $x_{n_k}\rightarrow x$ where $x\in A$ by compactness, but I'm not sure how to guarantee that $x=\sup A$ or $x=\inf A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $\inf$ and $\sup$ are limit points of $A$.  Since $A$ is closed, they will have to be members of $A$.

Comment: So let $\alpha=\sup A$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$, $\alpha-\epsilon \in A$. So, any epsilon neighborhood of $\alpha$ intersected with $A$ is different from $\alpha$; am I missing anything?

Comment: Your argument is not quite right.  It does not follow that $\alpha-\epsilon\in A$.  However, because $\alpha-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound, there is an $x\in A$ such that $\alpha-\epsilon<x<\alpha$.

Comment: Why isn't $\alpha-\epsilon$ necessarily in $A$ -- it's bounded and closed, so isn't it?

Comment: Consider the set $A=[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ and let $\epsilon=3/2$.  Since $\alpha=3$, $\alpha-\epsilon=3/2\notin A$.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that $x$ helps me. Do I want a sequence converging to it; why if so?

Comment: $x$ in in $A$ and is within $\epsilon$ of $\alpha$. Now, every $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $\alpha$ contains a member of $A$ which is different from $\alpha$.

Comment: So then any epsilon neighborhood of alpha contains something other than alpha and by definition alpha is a limit point?

Comment: See the edit to previous comment.

Comment: Oh great, this means that alpha is a limit point, and since $A$ is closed, alpha must be in $A$.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.